# escape forward slash by backslash using regular expressions of C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to match a string of any characters escaping forward slashes by backslash.

Some examples (in c++ string you need twice more backslashes then in the exmaples):

```
sdfsdfkjl/sdf  // does not match
sdfsdfkj\/sdf  // does match
sdfsdfk\\/sdf  // does not match
sdfsdf\\\/sdf  // does match
sdfsdfk\\/sd\\\/f  // does not match
sdfsdf\\\/sdf\\\/f  // does match
// and so on
```

I suppose there should be something like this

```
std::regex const regEx(
  "((?:(?:(?!\\\\)\\\\/)|(?:(?:\\\\\\\\)+\\\\/)|(?:[^/]))*)");
```

But it does not work for some reasons. My guess is that it is related to lookahead operation.

Comment: I take it you didn't like [the answer](http://rextester.com/BNPYLD9801) the [first time round](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120423)?

Comment: Please, try to understand why your answer is completely wrong, http://rextester.com/edit/BNPYLD9801.

Answer (score 2):

Do you initialize your regex objects with raw string literals?

A raw string literal has this format...

```
R"()"
```

So a regex initialization would look like this...

```
regex pat{R"()"};
```

You can also place any delimiter you want between the " and the ( or ) to be able to match any sequence.

Would you get matches if you tried a format that uses both types of slashes as delimiters? Say, something like this...

```
regex pat{R"\\/()\\/"};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    auto test_patterns = {
      R"(sdfsdfkjl/sdf)",
      R"(sdfsdfkj\/sdf)",
      R"(sdfsdfk\\/sdf)",
      R"(sdfsdf\\\/sdf)",
      R"(sdfsdfk\\/sd\\\/f)",
      R"(sdfsdf\\\/sdf\\\/f)"
    };

    std::cout << "With regex_search\n";
    std::regex r1(R".(^[^\\/]*(\\\\)*\\/).");    
    for (const auto& pattern: test_patterns) {
        std::cout << pattern << " : " <<
            (std::regex_search(pattern, r1) ? "match" : "no match") << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\nWith regex_match\n";
    std::regex r2(R".(^[^\\/]*(\\\\)*\\/.*).");    
    for (const auto& pattern: test_patterns) {
        std::cout << pattern << " : " <<
            (std::regex_match(pattern, r2) ? "match" : "no match") << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
With regex_search
sdfsdfkjl/sdf : no match
sdfsdfkj\/sdf : match
sdfsdfk\\/sdf : no match
sdfsdf\\\/sdf : match
sdfsdfk\\/sd\\\/f : no match
sdfsdf\\\/sdf\\\/f : match

With regex_match
sdfsdfkjl/sdf : no match
sdfsdfkj\/sdf : match
sdfsdfk\\/sdf : no match
sdfsdf\\\/sdf : match
sdfsdfk\\/sd\\\/f : no match
sdfsdf\\\/sdf\\\/f : match
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/FBO22615)

Comment: There must be std::regex_match not, std::regex_search, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: a) The question does not in fact mention `regex_match`. b) Why do you care which function is used, as long as it solves the problem? Anyway, if you insist, just add an extra `.*` at the end, and use `regex_match`. [Live example](http://rextester.com/QHD54414)

Comment: Well, try to explain the question. What exactly is wrong?